# add html inside a wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, conditional-statements

I have this code:

```
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
            <h3>UPCOMING DEBATES</h3>
            <?php
            $query = new WP_Query( array(
           'post_type' => 'debate',
           'post_status' => 'future',
           'orderby' => 'date', 
           'order' => 'ASC', 
           'posts_per_page' => 1 
        ) );

        if( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();



            }
        }
        ?>
            </div>
```

And inside that `if( $query->have_posts() ) {` I want to add this code:

```
<div class="post-title box">

    <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>


</div>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div class="entry-image" style="<?php echo $max_height; ?>"><?php

    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large', false, '' ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $src[0]; ?>" class="lightbox" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">

        <?php the_post_thumbnail( $featured_image_size ); ?>

    </a>

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

This code is retrieving the `post_title` and the `thumbnail_image`.

The problem is that I don't know how to add this inside my first code ?

I've tried to put it inside my if `if( $query->have_posts() ) {` but it doesn't work. It seems to be more complicated than just copy and paste.

Any suggestions on how can I make this? 
I'm a PHP beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
        <h3>UPCOMING DEBATES</h3>
        <?php
        $query = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type' => 'debate',
       'post_status' => 'future',
       'orderby' => 'date', 
       'order' => 'ASC', 
       'posts_per_page' => 1 
    ) );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

    ?>

        <div class="post-title box">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        </div>

        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

            <div class="entry-image" style="<?php echo $max_height; ?>"><?php
                $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large', false, '' ); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $src[0]; ?>" class="lightbox" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( $featured_image_size ); ?>
                </a>
            </div>

        <?php }

        }
    }
    ?>
        </div>
```